# How to convert a numpy to a float in python

Tags: python

I have numpy arrays as follows.

```
x = array([0.1])
y = array([0.2])
z= array([-0.05])
```

I want to get the value of them as a number. Therefore, I did the follwoing.

```
print(x.tolist()[0])
print(y.tolist()[0])
print(z.tolist()[0])
```

However, it gave me the following results which is incorrect.

```
0.09999999999999996
0.19999999999999998
-0.049999999999999975
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get `0.1, 0.2, -0.05` respectively.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: @Austin I used it. However, it still gives me `0.09999999999999996
0.19999999999999998
-0.049999999999999975`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
print(round(x.tolist()[0], 2))
print(round(y.tolist()[0], 2))
print(round(z.tolist()[0], 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
float(x[0])
float(y[0])
float(z[0])
```

and for precision, you can use

> round